# El Capitan 10.11.15 can't set disk with OS as startup disk, only boots if I reset nvram

Tags: osx, hard-disk, startup

Mac Pro (Mid 210)
Since installing El Capitan on new HGST 6T drive I can ONLY boot this system by resetting NVRAM. If I try to restart I get apple, progress meter, then circle with line through it symbol.

System has another separate drive with OS Mavericks. This drive can be set as startup drive and can boot with restart.

I tried ....
Boot to recovery mode, run disk utils on all drives...all fine
Moved all kernel extensions not found in recovery partition out of /Volumes/bhgstboot/Library/Extensions....still won't boot without resetting NVRAM

Try setting startup disk from system preferences. Click unlock, select my hgst drive, click on lock (does not let me lock). Sometimes it comes back with error from bless, most times it just hangs

```
4 # bless --info /Volumes/bhgstboot
finderinfo[0]:     56 => Blessed System Folder is /System/Library/CoreServices
finderinfo[1]: 8908212 => Blessed System File is /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
finderinfo[2]:      0 => Open-folder linked list empty
finderinfo[3]:      0 => No alternate OS blessed file/folder
finderinfo[4]:      0 => Unused field unset
finderinfo[5]:     56 => OS X blessed folder is /System/Library/CoreServices
64-bit VSDB volume id:  0x7254F8914231C18C
```

systemsetup doesn't see bhgstboot drive

```
8 # systemsetup -liststartupdisks
/Volumes/bootableOS_wd4T/System/Library/CoreServices
/System/Library/CoreServices

10 # systemsetup -getstartupdisk
```

If I startup holding down option /Volumes/bhgstboot shows up , I can select it but after Apple logo and progress bar , I get circle with line through it.

The ONLY way I can boot from this drive is by holding down Cmd-opt P-R

any ideas?